# What is TCP over file?

Tags: networking, tcp, tunnel, tunneling

I am trying to understand what's TCP over file.
I tried searching it on google, but except for a software, I didn't really find an answer.

Comment: Do you mean file descriptor?

Comment: There is no such thing. With more context it might be possible to find out what was really meant, but right now the question is lacking any useful information.